# How to make Parrot OS go full screen on HYPER-V?

Tags: fullscreen, hyper-v, parrot-os

I am testing Parrot OS and  would like to put it in full screen mode in Hyper-V

Tried seeking through parrotsec documentations but couldn't find any reference.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

Since Parrot OS is using Debian, I just tried to modify the Grub Setting by adding video=hyperv_fb:1440x900

nano /etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1440x900"

CTRL x + Y + Enter

sudo update-grub

sudo reboot

Then works as expected now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another option I found is to enable enhanced session mode on Hyper V. On host run in powershell:

```
Set-VM "YourVMName" -EnhancedSessionTransportType HVSocket
```

On guest parrot os I used this script:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mimura1133/linux-vm-tools/master/kali/2021.x/install.sh

Bonus is clipboard between host and guest also works after this.